# How to turn off auto rotation in aide

Tags: applications, 8.1-oreo

I am not able to turn off auto-rotation in aide app, i tried many times but i could not found any solution.
i also tried to find the option for rotation in aide setting but there was no option given as the same.
please help.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Some apps enforce auto rotation. There is nothing you can do about that.

Make sure your device has it shut off. Should be a quick tile (slide down twice from top of screen) that had a phone symbol. Make sure there are no circular lines around it, and it is not brightened/bolded